# Cannot install pyqt5

Tags: ubuntu, python3

I'm trying to install pyqt5 and I'm getting the following error :

```
$ sudo pip3 install pyqt5

Collecting pyqt5

From cffi callback <function _verify_callback at 0x7fbdc777f2f0>:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/OpenSSL/SSL.py", line 313, in wrapper
_lib.X509_up_ref(x509)
AttributeError: module 'lib' has no attribute 'X509_up_ref'

Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pyqt5 (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for pyqt5
```

I have no idea how to tackle this one anymore.

My Os :

Linux version 4.13.0-38-generic (buildd@lgw01-amd64-042) (gcc version 7.2.0 (Ubuntu 7.2.0-8ubuntu3.2)) #43-Ubuntu SMP Wed Mar 14 15:20:44 UTC 2018

I've got python 2.7.14  and  python 3.6.3

Answer (score 0):

You most likely just need to update the `OpenSSL` package or the `setuptools` package. You can do this using:

```
$ pip install --upgrade setuptools
$ pip install --upgrade pyOpenSSL
```

If you come across the same error upon upgrading the `pyOpenSSL` package, you may need to also update the `cryptography` package:

```
$ pip install --upgrade crytography
```

Occasionally, `pip` will not manage dependencies properly and thus upgrading packages manually in this fashion is required.

Comment: Tried it and I get : Requirement already up-to-date

Comment: Apologies, you may have to rerun the commands with `pip3` instead of `pip`.

Comment: If that does not work still, try running: `pip3 uninstall pyopenssl`, followed by `pip3 install pyopenssl`.

Comment: Same error ...Collecting pyOpenSSL
From cffi callback <function _verify_callback at 0x7ff60740d2f0>:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/OpenSSL/SSL.py", line 313, in wrapper
    _lib.X509_up_ref(x509)
AttributeError: module 'lib' has no attribute 'X509_up_ref'    ... always the same error reference when I try to use pip3 install ..maybe I should reinstall completely python3?